# Influence of Vertex Weights on Performance of Polyhedral TSP Algorithms

Tags: convex-polytopes, combinatorial-optimization

It is well known, that the optimal tours are invariant under the addition of vertex weights; it is also known, that minimum spanning trees provide an upper bound on the length of the shortest Hamilton cycle in a graph and, that the MST is sensitive to the addition/subtraction of vertex weights, which makes it possible to penalize vertices with high degree in the MST and thus improve the upper bound in some cases.

> **Questions:**
>
> are TSP algorithms, that are based on polyhedral methods, such as e.g. *Cut&Branch*, sensitive to the addition/subtraction of vertex weights in the sense, that the execution path from the input of a TSP instance to reporting the optimal solutions can vary, if vertex weights are added/subtracted?
>
> In case of an affirmative answer: what would be good criteria for the vertex weights to be added/subtracted (e.g. maximize sum of subtracted weights, that leave all edge weights non-negative; add large weights; add random weights)?

Comment: This sounds exactly like the *One-tree* relaxation: http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02713/NewLectures/bbtsp4.pdf

Comment: @JohnGunnarCarlsson that's exactly the case, but AFAIK only the numerical value of the upper bound is exploited by adding it as a constraint on the length of optimal tour; the edge-weights of the problem instance are however not modified - please correct me, if I'm wrong. What my questions aims at, is a bit different, namely what would happen, if we don't add the improved length-constraint and instead modify only the edge-weights of the problem instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but the one-tree relaxation definitely involves iteratively changing the edge weights.

Comment: So the answer to my question would be "yes" in the sense, that adding/subtracting vertex weights influences the execution of polyhedral TSP algorithms, even if the restriction on optimal tour length isn't tightened?